# Simple meaning of "A mellow edge isn't an oxymoron"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I got this as my astrology prediction.

> A mellow edge isn't an oxymoron. Buy
>   their drinks. Show them why you're so famous.

What oxymoron means is

> A figure in which an epithet of a contrary signification is added to a
>   word; e. g., cruel kindness; laborious idleness.

Still kind of confused regarding this sentence.

What does this phrase actually mean in simpler language?

Comment: Normally an edge is considered hard (sword-edge for example)

Comment: Just in case you hadn't run across ELL before, I think this would have made one fine question on the [ell.se] Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something "has an edge to it" then it is sharp. This comes from the [meaning of edge](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/edge#edge__8) being the sharp side of a blade.

[Mellow](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mellow) often means soft, or smooth. This is quite unlike something with an edge.

So saying something has "a mellow edge" could be seen as an oxymoron. However, the horoscope says it is not an oxymoron. I think that this declaration is a means to encourage you to take the opportunity to be yourself (i.e. relax, be mellow) while at the same time being sharp (i.e. witty and engaging).

So, really, it is an oxymoron, but by saying that the two *can* go together without contradiction, the horoscope is encouraging you to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary.com has the following definition for oxymoron:

> **ox·y·mo·ron**  ... noun, plural ox·y·mo·ra   ox·y·mor·ons.
>
> **Rhetoric** . a figure of speech by which a locution produces an incongruous, seemingly self-contradictory effect, as in “cruel
>   kindness” or “to make haste slowly.”

So 'mellow edge' **is** an oxymoron. The horoscope can't even get its English right.

The accurate statement would be

> A mellow edge isn't necessarily a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Hurrah! Nice catch. I fell into the trap of thinking about wine, cheese, and razors, so I didn't even perceive this gaffe until you brought it up. I never trusted horoscopes all that much, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 'mellow' connotes smooth or soft, and an 'edge' is usually something sharp (opposite of smooth). So, looking at that phrase one way you could say that mellow and edge are opposites, and that 'mellow edge' is somewhat contradictory or oxymoronic.

I think the stars (or your magazine's astrology-generation computer program) are telling you that you can be edgy (fun, interesting, desirable) and mellow (easygoing) at the same time and that they are not contradictory.